# Rewrite a Sentence and shorten it by including abbreviations

Tags: nlp, computer-science

I have a Text Summarization problem at hand, and given multiple suggestions/tutorials available on the web, I do not know where to start.

Problem Statement:
User enters a text, usually a description like:

> 1. Eyebolts Galvanized Steel M12 With Shoulder

or

> 2. Eyebolts Zinc Plated Steel 9/16"-12 With Shoulder

I would require AI/ML automation to help me convert this text into an abbreviated summary of 28 characters.

`Eyebolts Galvanized Steel M12 With Shoulder ==> EYBLT GLVSTL M12 WSHLDR`

`Eyebolts Zinc Plated Steel 9/16"-12 With Shoulder ==> EYBLT ZNPLTSTL 9/16" WSHLDR`

Is this a far-fetched idea/am I barking up the wrong tree here thinking AI will solve this problem? or is it within grasp with libraries like Gensim/Nltk etc. ?